# Sticky Footer Creating Infinite Scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, sticky-footer

Just what the title says! The sticky footer plugin I created (with some generous assistance from all you fine folk here) is working well, but it keeps creating this weird infini-scroll effect.

Any idea what's happening here? I'm stumped, though I suspect there's something in the jQuery I'm not knowledgeable enough about to fix.

Thanks for any assistance you can offer!

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$(window).bind("load", function() { 

       var footerHeight = 0, footerTop = 0, $footer = $("#footer"); 
       positionFooter();
       function positionFooter() {

           footerHeight = $footer.height();
           footerTop = ($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-footerHeight)+"px";

           if( ($(document.body).height()+footerHeight) < $(window).height()) {
                   $footer.css({ position: "absolute"}).animate({ top: footerTop },-1)
               } else {
                   $footer.css({ position: "static"})
               }  
           }

       $(window).scroll(positionFooter).resize(positionFooter)

    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#footer {
    clear: both;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 0 0;
    background: #315B71;
    border-top: 8px solid rgb(29, 71, 93);
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here's a fiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ZxupR/

Comment: I'm not seeing any scrolling issues on Safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to account for the 8px `border-top` style when setting the `top` value. Change:

```
footerHeight = $footer.height();
```

to

```
footerHeight = $footer.outerHeight();
```

on line 14 in your `jquery.footerstick.js` file.

This uses jQuery's [`.outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) instead of `.height()`.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/ZxupR/2/

Comment: Great stuff, and thank you for the smooth comments! However, it doesn't seem function on the site. I've made the change indicated here to my jQuery, but I'm still not seeing a resolution . . . which is odd because it works flawlessly in the fiddle. Any thoughts on this? 

Thank you for your efforts here!

Comment: @LukePatrick - no problem. I had the same issue when I loaded your site as well, just clear your browser's cache and it will work.

Comment: Thank you again! That did work well, only one more issue: On pages where it is indeed longer than the screen size, it seems like it's treating the footer as `position: fixed;`. Any idea why this might be? The jQuery looks accurate to me, as far as the if statement.

[link] (http://www.kangabloo.com/work/)

Comment: Hoop! Never mind, figured that out. If I set the `#wrap` section to any height, things get a bit weird. So, I'll not do that. Considering this one tied down! THanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I opened your website in web developer mode inside crome, your footer seems to be on position absolute. with an increment position top every time you scroll. Check that. As well as the code only happening when a certain resolution of the window is reached.